# How to configure Grails 3 + Spring Security to use multiple entry points, user domains

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm having difficulty correctly configuring spring security in a Grails 3 experiment (https://github.com/davebrown1975/grails-multientrypoint-security) to utilise 2 distinct User domains, in this case Montagues & Capulets. Each type of user should have their own login page, and restrictions on what they can or cannot access. I.e. A logged in Capulet should not be able to view pages of the Montagues and vice versa.

So to establish these rules, I have 2 Distinct User types, distinct views and auth pages, and custom filters, Authentication Providers and Entry Points.

Current behaviour however, as per my GebSpec is that an attempted call to a secured  Montague Page redirects not to the Montague Login page as intended but to the plugins default Login.  So perhaps the issue is the configuration of filters per below:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [
   'securityContextPersistenceFilter', 'logoutFilter',
   'authenticationProcessingFilter',
   'rememberMeAuthenticationFilter', 'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
   'exceptionTranslationFilter', 'filterInvocationInterceptor'
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],

  [pattern: '/capulets/**',    filters: 'securityContextPersistenceFilter,logoutFilter,capuletsAuthenticationFilter,' +
           'authenticationProcessingFilter,rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,anonymousAuthenticationFilter,' +
           'exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor'],

  [pattern: '/montagues/**',   filters: 'securityContextPersistenceFilter,logoutFilter,montaguesAuthenticationFilter,' +
           'authenticationProcessingFilter,rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,anonymousAuthenticationFilter,' +
           'exceptionTranslationFilter,filterInvocationInterceptor'],

    [pattern: '/**',             filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-montaguesAuthenticationFilter,-capuletsAuthenticationFilter']
]
```

Any help on this would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks,